# How to handle Freezable in a custom MarkupExtension?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've got a working [custom markup extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747254.aspx) which retrieves information out of the `DataContext` in a specific way (unimportant for this question).

All is well until I use this markup extension in elements that are not part of the visual or logical tree. In my particular example in the element `InputBindings`. In this scenario instead of retrieving a `FrameworkElement` as `DependencyObject` I get a `Freezable` (`KeyBinding`).

**How can I access the** `DataContext` **through code?**

My XAML code:

```
<UserControl.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding
        Key="CapsLock"
        Command="{wtc:CommandBinding {x:Static b:Commands.OpenTimeLine}}" />
</UserControl.InputBindings>
```

Code in my custom markup extension where I normally retrieve my `DataContext`:

```
protected override object ProvideValue(
    DependencyObject dependencyObject,
    DependencyProperty dependencyProperty )
{
    if ( dependencyObject is Freezable )
    {
        // TODO: How to handle freezable?
    }

    _frameworkElement = dependencyObject as FrameworkElement;
    if ( _frameworkElement == null )
    {
        throw new InvalidImplementationException(
            "The DataContextBinding may only be used on framework elements." );
    }

    if ( !_dataContextChangedHooked )
    {
        _frameworkElement.DataContextChanged += DataContextChanged;
        _dataContextChangedHooked = true;
    }

    return ProvideValue( _frameworkElement.DataContext );
}
```

---

The entire source code is online as well. I have quite an extensive class hierarchy for markup extensions.

[AbstractMarkupExtension](https://github.com/Whathecode/Framework-Class-Library-Extension/blob/master/Whathecode.PresentationFramework/Windows/Markup/AbstractMarkupExtension.cs) ⇐ [AbstractDependencyPropertyBindingExtension](https://github.com/Whathecode/Framework-Class-Library-Extension/blob/master/Whathecode.PresentationFramework/Windows/Markup/AbstractDependencyPropertyBindingExtension.cs) ⇐ [AbstractDataContextBindingExtension](https://github.com/Whathecode/Framework-Class-Library-Extension/blob/master/Whathecode.PresentationFramework/Windows/Markup/AbstractDataContextBindingExtension.cs) ⇐ [CommandBindingExtension](https://github.com/Whathecode/Framework-Class-Library-Extension/blob/master/Whathecode.PresentationFramework/Windows/Input/CommandFactory/CommandBindingExtension.cs)

Comment: This might be difficult, as far as i know the logic for that stuff is internal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is surprisingly easy. Assuming the `DataContext` you are looking for is the same as the `DataContext` of your root object you can simply use the [`IRootObjectProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xaml.irootobjectprovider.aspx). This provider is accessible through the `IServiceProvider` which is passed as an argument of `ProvideValue`.

```
var rootProvider = (IRootObjectProvider)ServiceProvider
                       .GetService( typeof( IRootObjectProvider ) );
_frameworkElement = rootProvider.RootObject as FrameworkElement;
```

There might be more complex scenarios where you have to traverse the tree (through [`LogicalChildren`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.logicalchildren.aspx)) in order to find the desired `DataContext`.

Answer (score 0):

Here would be the nasty reflection way:

```
var context = (FrameworkElement)typeof(DependencyObject)
    .GetProperty("InheritanceContext", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
    .GetValue(dependencyObject, null);
var datacontext = context.DataContext;
```

(The cast to `FrameworkElement` is *not* safe, `InheritanceContext` is also of type `DependencyObject`, the `InheritanceContext` usually is the object declaring the property in which the `Freezable` is used, if it is not a `FrameworkElement` you might need to recurse)

Comment: Unfortunately, `InheritanceContext` is `null`.

Comment: Curious, did you also test it on a `MarkupExtension` somewhere under `InputBindings`?

Comment: @StevenJeuris: No, maybe the fact that the InputBindings are a collection has to do with it, might test it again later...

Comment: Yes, I believe that is the actual problem. However, meanwhile I did manage to get [at least the `DataContext` of the root element](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9064750/590790), which is just fine for my purposes at the moment.

Comment: @StevenJeuris: I saw that, good idea but sadly not very universal